# How to Implement linkedin's TestButler library in Espresso test

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I am trying to implement [TestButler](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/08/introducing-and-open-sourcing-test-butler--reliable-android-test) library to remove flakiness of emulator.
One of the steps mentioned is to add following code to the test runner class:

```
package com.linkedin.util;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;
import com.linkedin.android.testbutler.TestButler;

public class ExampleTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    TestButler.setup(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void finish(int resultCode, Bundle results) {
    TestButler.teardown(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());

    super.finish(resultCode, results);
}
}
```

I am not sure where to insert this code as in my test cases i am using **@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably put it in *build.gradle* in *android* -> *defaultConfig*

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'com.linkedin.util.ExampleTestRunner'
```

to override the default runner

Comment: Doing so gives error:Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{test_package_path/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

Comment: Could you share your build.gradle file? Also are you running this from Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I am running it from android studio.Also in my build.gradle file I simply commented testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' and added the new class path here.

Comment: Have you copied ExampleTestRunner to this package in your project? Please also check in Android Studio run configuration for you test if it updated the runner to the new one.

Comment: Thanks., it worked.I was not changing the run configuration in Android studio.